# How to find and prove a soution set for an exponential inequality in 2 variables

Tags: number-theory, inequality

The function I have is $$x^{6y+1} < (x^{2y}+x^y+1)^3$$ for $x \ge 3$ and $y \ge 1$ where x and y are positive integers.

Intuitively the only solution I can find is $3^7 < (9+3+1)^3$ for $(x,y) = (3,1)$

I tried Induction but I'm only able to make it work 1 variable at a time. How would I prove this?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $~x \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 3}}, ~y \in \Bbb{Z^+},$

- Let $~\displaystyle f(x,y) = \left[x^{2y} + x^y + 1\right]^3.$
- Let $~\displaystyle g(x,y) = x^{6y+1}.$

You want to find all $(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y) > g(x,y)$.

You have determined that $f(3,1) > g(3,1).$

Empirically, $~f(3,2) < g(3,2)~$ and $~f(4,1) < g(4,1).$

Therefore, in order to conclude that the solution $(3,1)$ is unique, it is sufficient to demonstrate that :

- Result-1: $~[f(x,y_1) < g(x,y_1), ~y_2 > y_1] \implies f(x,y_2) < g(x,y_2).$
- Result-2: $~[f(x_1,y) < g(x_1,y), ~x_2 > x_1] \implies f(x_2,y) < g(x_2,y).$

---

$\underline{\text{Result-1}}$ 
Using induction, it is sufficient to show that

$f(x,y) < g(x,y) \implies $

$$f(x,y+1) < g(x,y+1). \tag1 $$

As $~y \to (y+1),~$ the RHS of (1) above changes from 
 $x^{6y+1}$ to $x^{6[y+1] + 1} = x^{6y+1} \times x^6.$

This means that the RHS of (1) has been multiplied by a *factor of* $(x^6)$.

Therefore, it is sufficient to show that as $~y \to (y+1),~$ 
the LHS of (1) has changed by a smaller amount.

The LHS of (1) has changed from 
$\displaystyle [x^{2y} + x^y + 1]^3 ~~\text{to}~~
[x^{2y+2} + x^{y+1} + 1]^3$, 
which is strictly less than 
$\displaystyle \left\{ ~[x^{2y} + x^y + 1] \times x^2 ~\right\}^3.$

So, overall, the change in the LHS of (1) is less than the change that would result if the LHS of (1) was multiplied by $x^6$.

Therefore, the LHS of (1) above, $f(x,y+1)$ has changed by a smaller amount than the RHS of (1) above, $g(x,y+1).$

Therefore, since $f(x,y) < g(x,y)$, you must have that $f(x,y+1) < g(x,y+1).$

---

$\underline{\text{Result-2}}$ 
Using induction, it is sufficient to show that

$f(x,y) < g(x,y) \implies $

$$f(x+1,y) < g(x+1,y). \tag2 $$

As $~x \to (x+1),~$ the RHS of (2) above changes from 
$~\displaystyle x^{6y+1}~$ to $~\displaystyle (x+1)^{6y + 1} = x^{6y+1} 
\times \left[\frac{x+1}{x}\right]^{6y+1}.$

This means that the RHS of (2) has been multiplied by a *factor of* $~\displaystyle \left[\frac{x+1}{x}\right]^{6y+1}.$

Therefore, it is sufficient to show that as $~x \to (x+1),~$ the LHS of (2) has changed by a smaller amount.

The LHS of (2) has changed from 
$\displaystyle [x^{2y} + x^y + 1]^3 ~~\text{to}~~
[(x+1)^{2y} + (x+1)^y + 1]^3$, 
which is strictly less than 
$\displaystyle \left\{ ~[x^{2y} + x^y + 1] \times \left[\frac{x+1}{x}\right]^{2y} ~\right\}^3.$

So, overall, the change in the LHS of (2) is less than the change that would result if the LHS of (2) was multiplied by $~\displaystyle \left[\frac{x+1}{x}\right]^{6y},~$ which itself is less than $~\displaystyle \left[\frac{x+1}{x}\right]^{6y+1}.$

Therefore, the LHS of (2) above, $f(x+1,y)$ has changed by a smaller amount than the RHS of (2) above, $g(x+1,y).$

Therefore, since $f(x,y) < g(x,y)$, you must have that $f(x+1,y) < g(x+1,y).$